# How do I correctly use .click on this select type from html coding in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

```
<select name="s" id="s">
    <option value="64752">Small</option>
    <option value="64753">Medium</option>
</select>
```

Here is the HTML code for the select type from the website

```
.realClick('select#s', {x: 1, y: 1})
.insert('input#s', size)
```

Here is part of my coding I have tried, I get the error "cannot find element: "select#s"

I am not really sure what else to try I am fairly new to automating. I use PhantomJS with real-click PhantomJS. Any ideas would be great. Thank you

Comment: Is the page you're trying to automate publicly available? It's possible the element isn't loaded before you attempt to manipulate the form

Comment: @dannybuonocore Yeah it is but I added in wait times so it would pretty much ensure it’s loaded fully plus there’s different buttons on the page that I was able to click but they were just attributes instead of a select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use click on selects. I remember when I was using PhantomJS a lot I had to set the selected index of the option I was trying to choose:

```
page.evaluate(function() {

  // Set the selected index
  var select = document.getElementById('s');
  select.selectedIndex = 1;

  // Trigger a change event
  var onChange = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  onChange.initEvent('change', false, true);
  select.dispatchEvent(onChange);

});
```

This should select the option `Medium`.

[More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) regarding the `onChange` parameters.

Comment: if there were a size large what would you change to select large?

Comment: You're asking if you wanted to select Large from the options? If it's the third option then choose 2 (indices start at 0)